# How to print help if no argument passed in bash

Tags: bash, shell

I have created a script in order to use arguments while running that script. How to check if there were no arguments provided ? It must shows print help if no argument passes.

```
while test -n "$1"; do
         case "$1" in
            -help|-h)
            print_help
            exit $ST_UK
            ;;
        --version|-v)
            print_version $PROGNAME $VERSION
            exit $ST_UK
            ;;
        --activeusers|-a)
            opt_var=$2
            au
            shift;;
        --dailyusers|-d)
            opt_var1=$2
            dau
            shift;;
        *)
    echo "Unknown argument: $1"
        print_help
        exit $ST_UK
        ;;
    esac
    shift
done
```

Comment: Use: `(( $# )) || print_help` the the top of your script

Comment: Great! It's working

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it the same way you would for any POSIX shell, by testing the `$#` (number of arguments) magic variable:

```
if [ "$#" -eq 0 ]
then
    usage >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: Or, if no arguments, set the args to "--help" and use the while loop: `[[ $# -eq 0 ]] && set -- -h`

Comment: @glenn - less good, because you want the error case to write to stderr and exit with a failure, but you want requested help to write to stdout and exit success.  That's why I prefer a `usage` function for this.